# Intelij Idea annotations error during android code compilation

Tags: java, android

During compitalion  get the following error

`Error:(10, 6) java: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)`

How to fix it? I try enable annotations in Default setting, but still does not work.

Comment: What jdk have you selected in the IDE? (File -> Project Structure -> Project). The SDK must be 1.5 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using java 1.3 when building android projects. Java 1.8 may not be compatible with the current set of Android tools. Try changing your projects settings to use 1.6 and see if it fixes this.

```
Project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> switch all references to 1.6
```

Comment: OK it works. But know I got error like this `pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.test
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`